# A ClickOnce installation failing because Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Core has to be installed in the GAC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

I'm assisting a colleague who's working on a new WPF app. He's using .NET Framework 4.5.2. We generate a ClickOnce deployment for users to run. I can install the app using the ClickOnce installer, but users can't. They're getting this error:

[image]

I looked up Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Core [on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Core/17.0.0-previews-3-31605-261). I did that because when I brought up package manager I couldn't find it. So, I looked for everything that starts with "Microsoft.VisualStudio". This is what I found:

[image]

I can't find a Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Core.dll in the project. So, I figure Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Core must be in one of those other assemblies. Of course, it might not be in any assembly that starts with "Microsoft.VisualStudio". But clearly, since the ClickOnce deployment is trying to install it in the GAC, it's in the solution somewhere. Is Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Core a part of some other package? If so, what other package? Looking at NuGet, I've not been able to find out what might be using it.

Comment: I think what that error is saying isbthst your code has a dependency on `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Core` and that that assembly must be installed into the GAC. I do see a NuGet package of that name. Maybe you need to play version upgrade tag, trying to get things correct.  You won't see this in your project (except as a reference), it's very likely in the GAC on your Dev boxes

Comment: I'm sure you're right. BTW, it isn't me whose made the build & release, its a colleague of mine. I was asked to look into it, since my colleague is on vacation. That might be why it didn't show up in the snapshots I showed, since I used my PC. My guess is that `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Core` is on my colleague's machine in his GAC.

Comment: In general, these days, an app should have no GAC dependencies except those delivered as part of the Framework.  If the plain vanilla framework install didn't put it there (or Windows didn't put it there), get it from NuGet.  I'm about 95% (or more) sure that ClickOnce can't do GACking